# webservice proxy returns null

Tags: c#, wcf, wsdl

This is the webservice URL I am trying to connect to and use some of the operations in it.
The operation to be used is RealTimeTransaction. 
This method takes a input Corerealtimerequest object and returns a CoreRealtimeResposne object. 
All is well. Web service returns a soap response which Fiddler is able to capture but the proxy returns null.

[https://orserviceb2btest.oracleoutsourcing.com/soa-infra/services/default/MMISSOAPRequestReceiver!1.0*soa_d48cf4e0-5e7b-43ad-b430-727180d48841/RouteEDITransactions_ep?WSDL](https://orserviceb2btest.oracleoutsourcing.com/soa-infra/services/default/MMISSOAPRequestReceiver!1.0%2asoa_d48cf4e0-5e7b-43ad-b430-727180d48841/RouteEDITransactions_ep?WSDL)

This wsdl contains many unresolved links. The wsdl references resolve when I change all occurrences of b2borexatest to orseviceb2btest. There are a total of 4 references to b2borexatest in the service url. By doing so, I was able to create a proxy class using svcutil.

```
https://b2borexatest.oracleoutsourcing.com/soa-infra/services/default/MMISSOAPRequestReceiver!1.0/CORERule220.wsdl 
to
 https://orserviceb2btest.oracleoutsourcing.com/soa-infra/services/default/MMISSOAPRequestReceiver!1.0/CORERule220.wsdl
```

This is how these objects are defined in the wsdl

```
<types>-<xsd:schema xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://www.caqh.org/SOAP/WSDL/" elementFormDefault="qualified">
<xsd:import schemaLocation="https://b2borexatest.oracleoutsourcing.com:443/soa-infra/services/default/MMISSOAPRequestReceiver!1.0*soa_d48cf4e0-5e7b-43ad-b430-727180d48841/RouteEDITransactions_ep?XSD=xsd/CORERule2.2.0.xsd" namespace="http://www.caqh.org/SOAP/WSDL/CORERule2.2.0.xsd"/>
    </xsd:schema>
    </types>-<message name="RealTimeRequestMessage">
    <part name="body" element="CORE-XSD:COREEnvelopeRealTimeRequest"/>
    </message>
    <message name="RealTimeResponseMessage">
    <part name="body" element="CORE-XSD:COREEnvelopeRealTimeResponse"/>
    </message>
```

THis is how a part of soap:Body on Fiddler request looks like

```
`<s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<COREEnvelopeRealTimeRequest xmlns="http://www.caqh.org/SOAP/WSDL/CORERule2.2.0.xsd">
<PayloadType xmlns="">X12_270_Request_005010X279A1</PayloadType>
<ProcessingMode xmlns="">RealTime</ProcessingMode><PayloadID xmlns="">461726944</PayloadID>
<TimeStamp xmlns="">2013-07-23T07:35:22Z</TimeStamp>
<SenderID xmlns="">SID</SenderID>
<ReceiverID xmlns="">RID</ReceiverID>
<CORERuleVersion xmlns="">`
```

Response from Soap UI or Fiddler. 
The object of my interest in COreRealtimResponse.
 This one is null when I am using a proxy to call to the service method.

```
      HTTP/1.1 200 OK
        Date: Fri, 19 Jul 2013 21:10:32 GMT
        Server: Oracle-Application-Server-11g
        Content-Length: 3030
        Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 01:00:00 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly
        Set-Cookie: _WL_AUTHCOOKIE_JSESSIONID=; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 01:00:00 GMT; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
        X-ORACLE-DMS-ECID: 004sUF1pzHw9PdyN06aAUF00037x000S4e
        SOAPAction: ""
        X-Powered-By: Servlet/2.5 JSP/2.1
        Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
        Connection: Keep-Alive
        Content-Type: multipart/related;type="application/xop+xml";boundary="----=_Part_52_444854407.1374268236586";start="<283134dc77544061b8c4d5788ee9bd44>";start-info="text/xml"
        Content-Language: en

        ------=_Part_52_444854407.1374268236586
        Content-Type: application/xop+xml;charset=UTF-8;type="text/xml"
        Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
        Content-ID: <283134dc77544061b8c4d5788ee9bd44>

        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
      <env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" <env:Body>
<COREEnvelopeRealTimeResponse xmlns:cor="http://www.caqh.org/SOAP/WSDL/CORERule2.2.0.xsd" xmlns="http://www.caqh.org/SOAP/WSDL/CORERule2.2.0.xsd"><cor:PayloadType>X12_271_Response_005010X279A1</cor:PayloadType><cor:ProcessingMode>RealTime</cor:ProcessingMode>
    <cor:PayloadID>339408072</cor:PayloadID>
    <cor:TimeStamp>2013-07-19T16:10:36.517-05:00</cor:TimeStamp>
    <cor:SenderID>SID</cor:SenderID>
    <cor:ReceiverID>RECID</cor:ReceiverID>
    <cor:CORERuleVersion>2.2.0</cor:CORERuleVersion>
    <cor:Payload>ISA*00*          *00*          ~</cor:Payload>
    <cor:ErrorCode>Successful</cor:ErrorCode>
    <cor:ErrorMessage>Envelope was processed successfully</cor:ErrorMessage>
</COREEnvelopeRealTimeResponse>
</env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
        ------=_Part_52_444854407.1374268236586--
```

Code:

```
 var ORrealTimeTrans = new ORMCDProxy.COREEnvelopeRealTimeRequest()
            {
                PayloadType = "X12_270_Request_005010X279A1",
                ProcessingMode = procMode,
                PayloadID = InterchangeControlNumber,
                CORERuleVersion = ruleVersion,
                SenderID = senderId,
                ReceiverID = receiverId,
                TimeStamp = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:22Z"),
                Payload = Query270
            };

 ORMCDProxy.COREEnvelopeRealTimeResponse resp = ORMCDProxy.RealTimeTransaction(ORrealTimeTrans);
```

This resp object is null.

http://webservices20.blogspot.com/2008/10/interoperability-gotcha-visual-studio.html documents the problem and solution would be to add a web reference instead of service reference.

But this is not an option for me because the service wsdl has unresolved links and I have no control over it.

Comment: Using a "Web Reference" is not what I'd call a "solution". That's a legacy technology not meant to be used for new development.

Comment: @JohnSaunders ok, do you have a suggestion for this?

Comment: I don't have time now to look at it in detail. In general, when you get null back from a web service it's because of a mismatch in the XML namespaces. The service is sending you "x", but you're expecting "y". Since you didn't get any "y", you get null, meaning "no y".

Comment: @JohnSaunders, Ok I think that's what's happening here. the service is returning something with cor:CORERealTimeResponse namespace. I am expecting with plain CORERealTimeResponse..I have to figure out a fix for this.

Comment: Notice that the namespace prefixes, like "cor:" don't matter. What matters is what the namespaces are declared to be in the "xmlns" attributes.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: This is a part of the response on Fiddler <env:Body><COREEnvelopeRealTimeResponse xmlns:cor="http://www.caqh.org/SOAP/WSDL/CORERule2.2.0.xsd" xmlns="http://www.caqh.org/SOAP/WSDL/CORERule2.2.0.xsd"><cor:PayloadType>X12_271_Response_005010X279A1</cor:PayloadType><cor:ProcessingMode>RealTime</cor:ProcessingMode

Comment: I have the response in the question also towards the end. xmlns = "http://www.caqh.org/SOAP/WSDL/CORERule2.2.0.xsd" and response is like referring to this as cardonoutreach.com.